# Flexbox wrap does not work properly in firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

Compare example below on chrome and firefox.

It wraps properly on chrome for me, but firefox instead of wrapping, stretches flexbox and overflows parent. So who is right here, chrome or firefox? And how can I achieve same effect as on chrome on both?

```css
html,
body,
#app {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#app {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#top {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="top">

  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="item">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting a min-height and min-width on parent like so

```
 #content {
 min-height: 0;
 min-width: 0; }
```

Comment: Your answer works in snippet I included perfectly, in my exact situation however content is wrapped in one more container to allow horizontal scrolling on overflow. To make it work I had to make that container flexbox as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help.